# Where can I find LinkGrammar libraries?

Tags: kde-plasma, kde4

While compiling kdepim on CentOS 6.4, cmake can't find LinkGrammar libraries.  Where should these libraries be found and installed?

```
unix >cmake .

... <snip> ...
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.3 (using /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.3/bin/qmake)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib64/libX11.so
-- Found libassuan-config at /usr/local/bin/libassuan-config
-- Found assuan v2.1.0
--  Checking whether assuan is usable...yes
-- Usable assuan found.
--  Includes:  /usr/local/include
--  Libraries: /usr/local/lib/libassuan.so;/usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so
-- Usable assuan found for Kleopatra
-- Could NOT find LinkGrammar (missing:  LinkGrammar_LIBRARIES LinkGrammar_INCLUDE_DIR)

CMake Error at mailcommon/filter/filterimporter/tests/CMakeLists.txt:15 
(add_akonadi_isolated_test_advanced):
  Unknown CMake command "add_akonadi_isolated_test_advanced"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkGrammar is a library currently being developed by the AbiWord community, and its website is [here](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/).

However, might I recommend installing KDE using your distribution's package manager instead? This should resolve the "painful" experience you're having trying to compile it yourself. Instructions for this can be found [here](http://alinuxblog.com/centos/how-to-install-kde-centos-6-3.htm).